# lookupedit can't see the items in it DevExpress

Tags: devexpress

I feel lookupedit control with the string values not in English in another language and when I click the down arrow it shows me that there are items but I can't see the values of them, and if i click it then i see the value on look up

Answer (score 0):

A lookup edit have at least one column, and if you can see rows, that mean that the `DataSource` of your control is set. And if you cann't see the values of the items, that mean that the column `FieldName` property is not set correctly.

Here is a DevExpress [documentation article about the lookup edit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic), it may help you. Note that there is some actions you can do using the designer, such as setting the `ValueMember` property, the `DisplayMember` property, adding columns.